# Python: Whats wrong with this class definition (indentation error)

Tags: python

I can't seem to see what's wrong with this code, yet I get an **IndentationError** when I run the script.

```
import web
import json

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'handleRequest'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class handleRequest:
    def GET(self, method_id):
        if not method_id: 
            return json.dumps({'ok':0})
        else:
            return json.dumps({'ok': method_id})

    def POST(self):
        i = web.input()
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This is the console error messages I get when I attempt to run the script:

```
>>>     def POST(self):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def POST(self):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>         i = web.input()
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    i = web.input()
    ^
```

I have checked the indentation - and its the same 4 spaces I have used throughout the file - am I missing something?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not "running the script", you're typing it into the REPL. Save the contents to a file and execute the file via e.g. `python somescript.py`.

Comment: You're right - it seems VIM was insering some non space (but invisible) chars during the "paste" operation. Lesson learned.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with your text editor doing anything strange. The problem is that you cannot paste verbatim code from a source file into the REPL, in the general case, and have it work. Please see the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

There is no indentation on the line between the end of `GET` and the beginning of `POST`.

This should be ok when python is executing a file but when typing into the REPL (as it appears you are), python takes the empty line as an end to the class `handleRequest`

Answer (score 0):

Are you pasting that into an interactive session?  You can't have line break between your methods (the blank line tells the interpreter that the class is complete)